# raphael js hover slows animation

Tags: raphael

Here is what I've got going

http://jsfiddle.net/lono1981/CvMEX/2/

```
var paper = Raphael("paper");

var gear1 = paper.image( "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55552239/Testing%20Stuff/gear1.png",20,20,171,171,171);

var gear2 = paper.image( "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55552239/Testing%20Stuff/gear2.png",175,30,43,43,43);

var gear3 = paper.image( "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55552239/Testing%20Stuff/gear3.png",190,70,84,84,84);

var anim1 = Raphael.animation({transform: "r360"}, 4000).repeat(Infinity);
gear1.animate(anim1);

var anim2 = Raphael.animation({transform: "r-360"}, 3500).repeat(Infinity);
gear2.animate(anim2);

var anim3 = Raphael.animation({transform: "r-360"}, 3500).repeat(Infinity);
gear3.animate(anim3);

var f_in = function() {
    gear1.stop();
};

var f_out = function() {
gear1.animate(anim1);
};

gear1.hover (f_in,f_out);
```

Basically, once the hover stops and restarts the animation, the animation slows down and doesn't repeat properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think I helped with the question, accept it so it won't show unanswered

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CvMEX/7/)**

```
var anim1 = Raphael.animation({transform: "...r360"}, 4000).repeat(Infinity);
gear1.animate(anim1);
```

You have to add `...` in your `transform()` whenever you want to append to your transform which you do every time you `hover`.

Good luck!